# Unable to create app, invalid filetype in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am learning Phonegap for the first time. This is a simple app. This will just show "hello world". But whenever I am trying to build it is showing me unable to create app, invalid filetype.

My html code id given below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        <title>Our Application</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="condova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.example.pgbuild"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Test</name>

    <description>
        Show Hello World
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com/blog/" email="ryan@adobe.com">
        Eddard Start
    </author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.2.0" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />

    <icon src="img/icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="img/splash.png" />
</widget>
```

I am following up and running with Phonegap by Lynda. I have included the img folder which contains all the icons. I have also included the cordova.ios.js file. I haven't renamed it because the person in the tutorial also didn't rename it.

Comment: I am really sorry for everything. There was a simple problem. I had written condova when it should have been cordova :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more shot in the dark:

You have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="condova.js"></script>
```

when I think you want cordova.js with an "r"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If it is as simple as a typo like that, welcome to the club. Sometimes it just takes a while to track down that completely insignificant, and yet crippling bug.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but are the files actually saved as .PNG instead of .png?

In a native XCode environment you can get the simulator to run extensions of the wrong case, but it will fail on the device unless the extensions are exact case, just a minor difference in how the device OS scours the bundle vs. the simulator OS

Comment: all the files are saved as .png, should i change them to .PNG? @ryan cumley

Comment: you just want to make sure the case matches between how they're saved and how they're referenced in code (both caps or both lowercase, as long as they match). It was a pretty wild shot in the dark on my part, but that was one of the few "file" items I saw in your code, so I took a chance.